# taking the orthogonal complement twice in a banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, orthogonality, hahn-banach-theorem

a direct consequence of the hahn banach theorem is the if $L\subset X$ is a closed subspace, then $(L^{\perp})_{\perp}=L$.
what I'm trying to understand is whether or not for every $L\subset X^*$ closed we similarly get that $(L_{\perp})^{\perp}=L$.
I get a strong indication from the book I'm reading that that is not the case, but I can't seem to find a counterexample.

Comment: subspace. of course that an orthogonal complement is always a linear space so it wouldn't make sense otherwise

Comment: You get the weak star closure of L

Comment: Take any $X$ that is not reflexive.  It's embedded in $X^{**}$.  The annihilator of $X$ in $X^*$ is zero, but the double annihilator in $X^{**}$ is all of $X^{**}$.

Comment: I don't quite understand your example. in the notations of the post, which space is you starting space? X? X*? if it is X, and you take L=X*, then the annihilator of L in X is zero whose annihilator in X* is again L=X*

Comment: @Aviv:  Starting with $\hat X$ the image of $X$ in $X^{**}$, its annihilator in $X^*$ is zero.  The double-annihilator in $X^{**}$ is all of $X^{**}$.

Comment: I see now. thank you! you can close the question